# OpenOffice extension to change UI behavior

Tags: user-interface, openoffice.org, extending

Is it possible to develop an extension to intercept some functions such as Save, Save As, Save All, Send by Email, Print, etc.
I would need to intercept both mouse click and shortcuts when applies.

Thanks on advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Look at `Tools> Customize...`

You can hook macros to these events.

Comment: You can get notifications but you can't change the behavior.

Comment: AFAIR there is a way, designing the macros as `FUNCTION`s and returning `FALSE` - but I can't find the answer now.   
OTOH see this thread in the AOO community forum  
https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=23144  
for intercepting the dispatched commands.

Comment: Do you know if the user can uninstall this macros from the UI?

Comment: If installed in user space libraries - they can (even if password protected).
Install system wide.